# tcl not working when using Seaborn and Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tcl, seaborn

I am facing this error working with Seaborn and Matplotlib. This is the code I am using to plot a line plot using seaborn.

```
fig_dims = (15, 8)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=fig_dims)
sns_plot =sns.lineplot( x="xaxis", y=map_rows, marker='o',  data = return_doc,dashes= False )
sns_plot.set_xticks(range(len(yx)))
sns_plot.set_xticklabels(x ,rotation=90)
ax.set_title('Word frequency')
sns_plot.set(xlabel="Words", ylabel = "frequency")
fig = sns_plot.get_figure()
```

I am getting this error.

> Error occurred in action: Convert To Table, Aborting... Traceback
>   (most recent call last):  File
>   "/home/shahid/.config/language-factory-ide/Transformation/Output/Convert
>   To  Table/script.py", line 146, in plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9,
>   16]) File
>
> "/home/shahid/Desktop/LF/pipeline-builder-ide/python/install/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2761, in plot return gca().plot( File
>   "/home/shahid/Desktop/LF/pipeline-builder-ide/python/install/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 879, in gca return gcf().gca(**kwargs) File
>   "/home/shahid/Desktop/LF/pipeline-builder-ide/python/install/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 611, in gcf return figure() File
>   "/home/shahid/Desktop/LF/pipeline-builder-ide/python/install/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 546, in figure **kwargs) File
>   "/home/shahid/Desktop/LF/pipeline-builder-ide/python/install/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py",
>   line 3337, in new_figure_manager return
>   cls.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, fig) File
>   "/home/shahid/Desktop/LF/pipeline-builder-ide/python/install/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py",
>   line 876, in new_figure_manager_given_figure window =
>   tk.Tk(className="matplotlib") File
>   "/home/shahid/Desktop/LF/pipeline-builder-ide/python/install/lib/python3.7/tkinter/**init**.py",
>   line 2023, in **init** self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName,
>   className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
>   _tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: /tools/deps/lib/tcl8.6
>   /home/shahid/Desktop/LF/pipeline-builder-ide/python/install/lib/tcl8.6
>   /home/shahid/Desktop/LF/pipeline-builder-ide/python/lib/tcl8.6
>   /home/shahid/Desktop/LF/pipeline-builder-ide/python/install/library
>   /home/shahid/Desktop/LF/pipeline-builder-ide/python/library
>   /home/shahid/Desktop/LF/pipeline-builder-ide/python/tcl8.6.9/library
>   /home/shahid/Desktop/LF/pipeline-builder-ide/tcl8.6.9/library This
>   probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.

I have tried uninstalling and installing tcl and tkinter. nothing seems to be working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Can%27t+find+a+usable+init.tcl

Comment: @BradLanam many of those questions are unanswered and some answered are workarounds, not solving the issue.

Comment: The core problem is that Tcl and Tk have a few places they look for their scripted pieces, and simply can't find those bits in any of the places they've been told to look in. We're working on trying to get a way to embed the critical pieces in the Tcl and Tk DLLs directly, but that's going to be in 8.7 _at the earliest_ since it requires new API and changes to the build system.

Comment: @DonalFellows so what is the solution at the moment?

Comment: @DonalFellows I have done lot of work and now I am getting this error. tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "tcl_findLibrary"

Comment: Still sounds broken. They need _all_ the files from https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcl/dir?ci=core-8-6-9&name=library and https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/dir?ci=core-8-6-9&name=library (OK, maybe not the `demos` from the second one)